# Typesctipt error with Firestore functions: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing the [Fireship Cloud Functions Course](https://fireship.io/courses/cloud-functions/http-basic/) course. In that lesson he is covering HTTP cloud functions. I have literally line for line the same exact code but I get this error when I run `firebase serve --only functions`

```
+  functions: Using node@14 from host.
i  functions: Watching "C:\Users\lover\CS-230\WVU_CS230_2021.08_Group06\COVID19-Tracker\functions" for Cloud Functions...
!  C:\Users\lover\CS-230\WVU_CS230_2021.08_Group06\COVID19-Tracker\functions\src\index.ts:1
export { basicHTTP } from './http';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at initializeRuntime (C:\Users\lover\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:640:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async handleMessage (C:\Users\lover\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:684:20)
!  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
   - It appears your code is written in Typescript, which must be compiled before emulation.
   - You may be able to run "npm run build" in your functions directory to resolve this.
```

I tried `npm build` before running, I tried installing yarn as per [this recommendation](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/129%5D), and I have also tried `npm run serve`. None have which have helped.

I have node.js v14.18.0 installed, express.js v4.17.1, firebase v9.4.1, and I am using windows 10.

Below is the entirety of my https.ts file

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp(); // we only need to call this once in ONE file! 
                      //if this is done more than once error for duplicate apps will appear 

export const basicHTTP = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send('Hello from FireBase!');
});
```

Below is the entirety of my index.ts file

```
export { basicHTTP } from './http';
```

[image: These are how my directories are organized]

And finally my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't deploy ts code, you need to compile it to normal js. In this case you can just use npm run build and then try again.

Comment: I get the same error after running npm run build. I ran npm run build both in the main directory and the functions directory and It did not help. 

`export { basicHTTP } from './http';
^^^^^^ 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Comment: You are still running the index.tx, you need to go to the build folder and run it

Comment: So the problem was in my package.json file. I had changed the file so that main included ./src/index.ts when it should go to lib/index.js because like you said you cannot deploy ts code! That didn't make sense to me before since I'm super new at this but now it does. It's up and running now. Thank you for your help @DerEchteKroate!